# Changing Input field value not showing up on webpage using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have an input field on a webpage that I want to access and set the value. To do so, I have the following:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("input")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', element)
browser.wait_until_element_is_visible(element)
element.clear()
driver.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{input_value}"', element)
```

The above works but sometimes when setting the input field's value it doesn't actually set it on the webpage, so the input field will be empty. But when I output: `print(element.get_attribute('value'))` , it is returning exactly what I wanted the input field to have (so following the example, *`input_value`*).

I want to change the input field on the UI by setting the input's value attribute and prefer not to use `sendKeys()` as these input strings are very long. So does anyone know how to make the input field value show up on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

To access and set the value you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "input"))))
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "input")))
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys(input_value)
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```